# Delegate to another object's operator->

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Writing at alias template that will deduce the return type of some type `T`'s `operator->`, so far I have this

```
template <typename T>
using arrow = decltype(std::declval<T&>().operator->());
```

which works for all class types, but doesn't work for pointers. A similar problem exists trying to actually call the `->`

```
template <typename T>
struct D {
    T t;
    arrow<T> f() { 
        // not valid to call .operator->() on pointers
        return t.operator->();
    }
};
```

How can I make this function get the correct return type declared, and delegate correctly for both class types and pointers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a pointer, the type of its `operator->()` its own type, and the resulting object has its same value.  With another level of indirection, a helper struct can be specialized for pointer types

```
template <typename T>
struct ArrowHelper {
    using type = decltype(std::declval<T&>().operator->());
    type operator()(T& t) const {
        return t.operator->();
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct ArrowHelper<T*> {
    using type = T*;
    constexpr type operator()(T* t) const noexcept {
        return t;
    }
};
```

To simplify usage, an alias template and a function can be defined easily

```
template <typename T>
using arrow = typename ArrowHelper<T>::type;

template <typename T>
arrow<T> apply_arrow(T& t) {
    return ArrowHelper<T>{}(t);
}
```

the delegating member function then becomes

```
template <typename T>
struct D {
    T t;
    arrow<T> f() { return apply_arrow(t); }    
};
```

Comment: `static type apply_arrow(T* t)` I would `constexpr type operator()(T*t)const` instead.  Stateless callable pattern.